# How to refer to another instance in the iterate of the XForms action element?

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0, xsltforms

I am using an XForms action along with `iterate`. The `iterate` selects a set (using XPath) of nodes and repeats the action for it.The problem is I have multiple conditions for selecting the node set.

1. There should not be a `readOnly` node.
2. Should not be part of the `ignoreProperties` list (this list is in another instance).

Code:

```
<xf:action ev:event="setValues" iterate="
    instance('allProps')/props/prop[
        not(readOnly) and
        not(instance('ignoreProperties')/ignoredProperties/property[text() = name]
    ]
">
```

**The first condition `not(readOnly)` works.** But the second condition does not work. I feel there is some problem with the context of the XPath nodes.

How should I replace the second condition to achieve the result ?

The target XML is a simple `ignoredProperties` document:

```
<ignoredProperties>
  <property>c_name</property>
  <property>c_tel_no</property>
</ignoredProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<xf:action ev:event="setValues" iterate="
    instance('allProps')/props/prop[
        not(readOnly) and
        not(name = instance('ignoreProperties')/ignoredProperties/property)
    ]
">
```

The `=` operator works against multiple nodes, returning all the ones that match. With `not()` you can express that you don't want a match.

Explicitly selecting `.../property/text()` will not be necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The result is the same as before. The ignore properties are still part of the result.

Comment: Post the XML this is targeted at.

Comment: I have added the sample target XML. However, I realised that name = 'c_name' will work and produce a result with single property as expected but the not(name = 'c_name') does not have any effect (was expecting total properties -c_name). Are you sure about the not part ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your calls to `instance()`. If you have:

```
<xf:instance id="ignoredProperties">
    <ignoredProperties>
        <property>c_name</property>
        <property>c_tel_no</property>
    </ignoredProperties>
</xf:instance>
```

Then `instance('ignoredProperties')` returns the `<ignoredProperties>` element. So you should write:

```
<xf:action ev:event="setValues" iterate="
    instance('allProps')/prop[
        not(readOnly) and
        not(instance('ignoreProperties')/property[text() = name])
    ]
">
```

This also assumes your `allProps` instance has a `<props>` root element.

Further, the second condition appears wrong, as already shown in another answer. Write instead:

```
not(name = instance('ignoreProperties')/property)
```

In XPath 2, you could clarify that your `not()` are testing on node existence by using `empty()` instead:

```
<xf:action ev:event="setValues" iterate="
    instance('allProps')/prop[
        empty(readOnly) and
        not(name = instance('ignoreProperties')/property)
    ]
">
```